# mt_rand and rand not changing on page reload

Tags: php, random

I am having an odd issue with PHP. Here's my code:

```
<?php $rand = mt_rand(0,99);?>
<!doctype html5>
<html>
<head>
<title>MCAP</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:<?php echo $rand;?>%;background:blue no-repeat left center;background-size:100% 100%;height:100%;"><?php echo $rand;?>%</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the page will not update the number when I refresh it.

The site: http://play.elementfx.com

It will show a random number when I initially load the page, and when I refresh it once, but refreshing the page any more makes no difference. I am using an iPhone SE on Safari on iOS 11.0.2, in case that matters.

EDIT: It seems like a cache issue, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a server side cache for your PHP script response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 08 Oct 2017 20:17:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish: 291144118 290391078
Age: 7
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 5
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

Disable the cache in your server configuration or ask the administrator to do so.

Comment: Could you please add the header to change it to?

Comment: @SamuelWilliams You have to ask the administrator how to configure the installed cache.

Answer (score 0):

safari cache you page try this

Go to `Safari > Empty Cache`, or hit <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. To refresh, click the refresh button on the addressbar or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Another tip. If you want to restore Safari, like completely clear all the caches, or parts of it, go to `Safari > Reset Safari`. I use it usually when I need to clear a lot of memory from Safari, for it will clear the webpage screenshots, the cookies, the favicons, etc.

---

**Edit:** On the latest version of `Empty Cache` isn't on the `Safari` menu any more. It's now on the `Develop` menu. To show the `Develop` menu it, go to `Safari > Preferences...`, click the `Advanced` tab, and check `Show Develop menu in menu bar`. The keyboard shortcut remains unchanged, though.

`Safari > Reset Safari` isn't an option any more. To clear history you can use `History > Clear History...` and to clear cookies/local storage data, go to `Safari > Preferences...`, click the `Privacy` tab, and either click `Remove All Website Data...` or `Details...` to view and remove it for individual sites.

Comment: I'm using iOS, not a Mac